# Unable to run PubSubSource on Flink cluster

Tags: apache-flink, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I've wrote a minimal Flink application trying to read data from PubSub.

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.enableCheckpointing(10000L)
env.addSource(
  PubSubSource.newBuilder()
    .withDeserializationSchema(new SimpleStringSchema)
    .withProjectName("PROJECT")
    .withSubscriptionName("SUBSCRIPTION")
    .build())
  .print()
env.execute("job")
```

This program can be run directly (`sbt run`) successfully, but if I submit it to a Flink cluster, I got the following error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot find a NameResolver for pubsub.googleapis.com:443
```

I've tried to run clusters in different machines/environments, but none of them works.

- OS: macOS Catalina / Ubuntu 18.04
- Flink version: 1.13.1 / 1.12.2
- Scala version: 2.12.13 / 2.11.12
- JVM: Oracle 8&11, OpenJDK 8&11

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/sayuan/3ad5c96427fa92ad21885890c373e50a) for code, `build.sbt` and full error message.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62913324/406803) said, I need to keep those files in `META-INF/services`.

After I remove the following line, everything works fine.

```
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
```